# cakephp create select from database

Tags: php, database, cakephp, drop-down-menu

I am trying to develop a form using cakePHP.

```
 <div class="links form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
     <?= $this->Form->create($link) ?>
     <fieldset>
         <legend><?= __('Add Link') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('section_id', ['options' => $sections]);
        echo $this->Form->control('link');

        //how do I make this display a text value
        echo $this->Form->control('image_id', ['options' => $images]);

        echo $this->Form->control('active');
        echo $this->Form->control('created_on');
    ?>
     </fieldset>
     <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
     <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
 </div>
```

It creats a select element

```
 <select name="image_id" id="image-id">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
 </select>
```

What I want it to display is

```
 <select name="image_id" id="image-id">
      <option value="1">item a</option>
      <option value="2">item b</option>
      <option value="3">item c</option>
      <option value="4">item d</option>
 </select>
```

Note that  the data is stored in a database table 'images' with the id field 'id' and the desired text in 'file'

How do I make it create the select element from the database, using the desired text value rather than the id value for the option text value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create select field using data from your db:

In your ImagesTable:

Make sure you have display field set properly:

```
$this->displayField('file');
```

In your controller:

```
$images = $this->Images->find("list");
$this->set(compact("images"));
```

In your template file:

```
$this->Form->control("image_id", ["type" => "select"]);
```

More info: [Form Helper](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html)

Comment: Where do I put this $this->displayField('file');

Comment: You should have method `initialize()` in your ImagesTable.php file, which should be located in src/Model/Table. It can be already set to use 'id' field, if so change it to field that you want to be considered as primary display field. If not, just add a line to end of that method.

Comment: Thanks. The only part I needed to actually change from the auto generated code, was this line in the initialize() function. Everything else was already as you suggested. It is now working as desired!